# How to find the href inside of an element with cypress?

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress

The main problem in here is that we don't know the party record id until we create the opportunity inside of salesforce. For the same reason, I have to see if it is a way to get the href links and from there save them into a fixture file to be able to use that data in the future.

Example:

[image]

Code | Cypress:

```
cy.get('table').get('tbody').get('tr').get('td').get('th').should('be.visible')
```

HTML:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also make use of the locator `[data-refid="recordId"]`, invoke the `href` attribute and save it in a fixtures file.

```
cy.get('[data-refid="recordId"]').each(($ele) => {
    cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/links.txt', $ele.attr('href'), {
        flag: 'a+'
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilise the `invoke` method.
You’ll end up with something like this: `cy.get(‘a’).invoke(‘href’)`